# React app homepage loses the ability to scroll after navigating elsewhere and returning

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm building a web app using React and have noticed that when I shrink my browser to a mobile size and navigate from the homepage to any other page and back, the homepage - and only the homepage - loses the ability to scroll. I changed from a top navbar to a bootstrap Offcanvas as my navbar when in a mobile screen sizing, if this helps. Below is the div code:

```
return (
    <div style={{ overflowX: "hidden" }}>
      <div
        style={{
          background: "linear-gradient(to bottom, #73a2d2, #a0b4cd)", 
          height: "100vh", 
          width: "100vw"
        }}
      >
        //content in here 
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#dad9d1",
          padding: "4rem",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          alignItems: "center", 
          textAlign: "center",
        }}
      >
        //content in here 
      </div>
    </div>)
```

I've tried:

- Removing and changing overflow settings
- Setting scroll position
- Changing height from 100vh to rem, which works, but does not have the view height effect I want where it always fills the view.